# What is the song in My Hero Academia that begins when Midoriya and Todoroki fight in Season 2 Episode 10 (before Todoroki uses fire)

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

The song has these "harp" sounds in the background

You can listen to it [here](https://youtu.be/J8dCHaKJiCc?t=140) around 2:20 minute like this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I finally found it!

The song name is "Boku no Hero Academia Season 2 OST - Go Seize It"

[Go Seize It](https://youtu.be/rRmEmvnUZB8?t=87)

Comment: Nice. If I might suggest, please include the title of the song and any additional or relevant information (album, artist, etc) about the song in your answer.

Comment: Please accept your own answer...